# How can I check if a file exists on FTP server?

Tags: android, file-exists, ftp-client

I am using apache FTPClient on android. I want to download a file from ftp server. But I want check if it exists on server before downloading. How can I check this?

Thanks,

my code:

```
public static boolean getFile(String serverName, String userName,
        String password, String serverFilePath, String localFilePath)
        throws Exception {

    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftp.connect(serverName);
        int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftp.disconnect();
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (ftp.isConnected()) {
            try {
                ftp.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException f) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

    try {
        if (!ftp.login(userName, password)) {
            ftp.logout();
        }           
        ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        OutputStream output;

        output = new FileOutputStream(localFilePath);           
        ftp.retrieveFile(serverFilePath, output);
        output.close();

        ftp.noop(); // check that control connection is working OK
        ftp.logout();
        return true;

    } catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (ftp.isConnected()) {
            try {
                ftp.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException f) {
                throw f;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] files = ftp.listnames();
```

look files if desired file name is include...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `ftpClient` is an instance of `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient`:

```
public boolean fileExists(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    String[] files = ftpClient.listNames();

    return Arrays.asList(files).contains(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the client sends RETR  and the server responds with an error code 550 you can be pretty sure that the file does not exist or you don't have permission to fetch it...  Since the FTP spec is a little loose you might just assume for any error in the range 550 - 559 which indicates permanent filesystem error.

Answer (score -2):

```
InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(filePath);
 if (inputStream == null || ftpClient.getReplyCode() == 550) {
// it means that file doesn't exist.
}


or

FTPFile[] mFileArray = ftp.listFiles();
// you can check if array contains needed file
```

Comment: The completePendingCommand() must be added to prevent problem with following FTP commands.